# Using multer with express and typescript

Tags: typescript, express, multer

Im using multer to parse form data that contains text and an image. When I try to console log my fields, it says that they are both undefined. Any ideas as to why this might be happening?

Here is the postman post request:
[image: postman]

```
const uploadThumbnailArray = [
  { name: 'thumbnail'},
  { name: 'notesId'}
]

app.post("/test_form", upload.fields(uploadThumbnailArray), async (req, res) => {
  try {
    const files = req.files as { [fieldname: string]: Express.Multer.File[] };

    console.log(files['thumbnail'])
    console.log(files['notesId'])
    var notesId: string = req.body.notesId
    const notesRef = admin.firestore().collection("notes_test").doc(notesId);

    res.json({ message: `succesfully uploaded thumbnail ${notesRef.id}` });

  } catch (error) {
    console.log(error);
    res.status(500).send(error);
  }
});
```

Answer (score -1):

Here you trying to take `notesId` from multer middleware. Multer only supports binary files.

Try to remove `notesId` from multer

`const uploadThumbnailArray = [{ name: "thumbnail", maxCount: 1 }];`

and just keep the `thumbnail` property.

```js
const express = require("express");
const multer = require("multer");
const app = express();
const port = 3000;

app.use(express.json());

var upload = multer({
  dest: "uploads/",
  preservePath: true
});

app.get("/", (req, res) => {
  res.status(200).send("Hello world");
});

const uploadThumbnailArray = [{
  name: "thumbnail",
  maxCount: 3
}];

/* 
//You can use this
app.post('/photos/upload', upload.array('photos', 12), function (req, res, next) {
  // req.files is array of `photos` files
  // req.body will contain the text fields, if there were any
})

*/

//Upload route
app.post("/upload", upload.fields(uploadThumbnailArray), (req, res, next) => {
  try {
    console.log(req.body);
    console.log(req.files);
    return res.status(201).json({
      message: "File uploaded successfully",
    });
  } catch (error) {
    console.error(error);
  }
});

app.listen(port, () =>
  console.log(`Hello world app listening on port ${port}!`)
);
```

Now try to run this application and test,

[image: Postman]

Now console `req.files`

[image: Output]

From here you can access storage location and file details for saving in the database

Comment: I tried this fix, and both fields logged as `[Object: null prototype] {}`. I then tried this medium article [article](https://medium.com/developer-rants/uploading-form-fields-and-files-at-the-same-time-with-multer-node-js-typescript-c1a367eb8198), but to have the same results. My express config is about the same as the article (expect for the start() thing).

Comment: Did you used this middleware? `app.use(express.json());`

Comment: yes. then i started using body parser + the multer upload for form data as per the medium article. I think the issue might be typescript, but i really dont want to go back to javascript.

Comment: I don't think so the problem with TypeScript. You should check the code again